# find a probability 21

Tags: probability

Two soldiers A and B shoot a bullet towards a target. If the probability that 
$A$ shot the target is $0.4$ and $B$ shot the target is $0.7$ Find the probability of:

a. Only one shot the target

b. At most one of them shot the target

My solution:

a. $P(A \cup  B) - P(A \cap B)$
since A and B are independent, then
$$P(A \cap B)= P(A)\times P(B) = 0.4 \times 0.7=0.28$$
then
$$P(A \cup B) = 0.4+0.7-0.28 =0.82$$
then the required quantity equals $0.82 - 0.28 = 0.54.$

b. $P(A' \cap B') = P(A \cup B)'= 1- P(A \cup B)= 1- 0.82 = 0.18$

Does the solution look correct or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Not clear on your answer for $B$. Should be $1-P(A\cap B)$, no?

Comment: Do you it should be P(A' U B') ? @lulu

Comment: Yeah, that should work.

Comment: $P(A'\cup B')=1-P(A\cap B)$. See my answer as to why this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a) you could use the law of total probability: set $A$: only one hits, this becomes:
$$
P(A) = P(A|S_1)P(S_1) + P(A|S_2)P(S_2)
$$
You are given marginal probabilities. For the conditional, it means: $P(A|S_1)$: probability the first one hits AND the second misses (and vice versa), so $P(A|S_1) = 0.4 \times 0.3$ and $P(A|S_2) = 0.7 \times 0.6$. Now you can plug all the values back into the equation above and get the probability.

This, of course, assumes that events are statistically independent.

Comment: If the required is the probability of no one hit the target would it be P(A' intesect B') = 1- P(A U B) ?

Comment: yes assuming independence, probability of two failures is the product of probabilities of each failure

Comment: Thank you @Alex 6

Comment: May you recommend me a simple book discusses the probability and combinatorics @Alex 6

Comment: well there are tonnes, I learnt mine ages ago tbh) try a good entry-level course on Coursera mb?

Answer (score 5):

Your first answer is indeed correct. Perhaps a quicker way to do it would be to say $$\underbrace{P(A')}_{A\text{ does not hit}}=0.6; \underbrace{P(B')}_{B\text{ does not hit}}=0.3$$
then Probability of only one hitting is:
$$P(B)P(A')+P(A)P(B')=0.54$$

---

For the second, add $P(A')P(B')$ for when neither of them hit; so:
$$0.54+0.18=0.72$$

You could also say that this is $1-P(\text{both hit})=1-P(A\cap B)=1-0.28=0.72$

Comment: Thank you @Rhys Hughes

Comment: No problem, all make sense?

Comment: yes i got it @ Rhys Hughes